# How to enable Graphical Remote Control to Ubuntu OS using command line?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, remote-control

I found a guide which helps to enable remote control for Ubuntu from graphical log-in.  I'm using EC2 server and need to enable this using putty command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself here - not sure if it works

Enabling Remote Desktop in Ubuntu ([link1](http://sidrit.wordpress.com/2008/08/03/enable-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-from-command-line/), [link2](http://www.samlesher.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-704-enabledisable-remote-desktop-from-the-command-line))

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the X11 forwarding option under SSH->X11, or the port-forwarding option under SSH->Tunnels.

For example, you can forward port 3389 to a network you're connecting to, then use the "Remote Desktop Connection" program (in Windows 7, maybe others too) to connect to another Windows machine, or any machine running an RDP server (e.g., xrdp for Linux).

RDP is usually faster than VNC or X11, but it's not secure (except that it's encrypted through the SSH connection).